# Struts2 link as button

Tags: java, struts2

I was wondering if the struts2 link (`<s:a>`) could have the same behave of a submit button (`<s:submit>`)?

Comment: if you are not sure how javascript works, you can consider using some plugin(framework) to ease your work. struts2-jquery-plugin is a good choice, here is the link: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, if you use JavaScript to submit the form in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function logout() {
            document.getElementById("form1").action = "checkliveuser?action=logout";
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        }
    </script>
.
.
.
other HTML code
.
.
.
<s:form action="chkUser" method="post" id="form1"  >
<s:a onclick="logout();" href="#" >Logout</s:a>

</s:form>
```